# Not able to use GPU for tensorflow programs:

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I tried to get the available device on my PC. I get the following with no gpu:

`>>> device_lib.list_local_devices()
[name: "/cpu:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 14983405983464524929
]`

When I tried to do nvidia-smi, the screen shows following:

```
'nvidia-smi 
Tue Aug  8 17:33:19 2017       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26                 Driver Version: 375.26                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 0000:01:00.0      On |                  N/A |
|  0%   40C    P8    15W / 230W |   1608MiB /  8112MiB |      4%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       928    G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            1606MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
'
```

I also tried

```
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64
```

and got following:

```
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so.5 is not a symbolic link
```

Comment: how did u install tensorflow?

Comment: conda3 installation

Comment: did u install `tensorflow-gpu` or just `tensorflow`

Comment: tensorflow-gpu installation